# How to Delete the Digital Ocean Space Image from Python Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, digital-ocean

Please let me know any reference or sample code to how to delete the Digital Ocean Space Image from Python Django, There is example for list and upload the image in Space Image.

Please help me to find the way for my solution

**Getting Error like:** 'S3' object has no attribute 'delete_file'

Please refer sample code like this

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client('s3',
                        region_name='nyc3',
                        endpoint_url='https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                        aws_access_key_id='********',
                        aws_secret_access_key='********')
client.delete_file('inspxotestspace',  # Name of Space
                    imagename1)  # Name for remote file
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards, Kishore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `delete_file` to `delete_object` like this

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client('s3',
                        region_name='nyc3',
                        endpoint_url='https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                        aws_access_key_id='********',
                        aws_secret_access_key='********')
client.delete_object(Bucket='inspxotestspace',  Key='imagename1')
```

And you must include: `Bucket=('your_bucket_name')` and `Key=('your_file_name')`

Comment: Getting like this **TypeError: delete_object() only accepts keyword arguments.**

Comment: Yes, you must use ```client.delete_object(Bucket='bucket-name', Key='path/to/spaces/file')```, without specifying keywords `Bucket` and `Key` will through the exception **TypeError: delete_object() only accepts keyword arguments**

Comment: I'm passing the both bucket and key but getting same error  **TypeError: delete_object() only accepts keyword arguments**
        
        **client.delete_object('inspxotestspace',  'file_name') **

Comment: Your request should not be `client.delete_object('inspxotestspace', 'file_name')`, it should be `client.delete_object(Bucket='inspxotestspace', Key='file_name')`. dont forget to include **Bucket=** before your bucket name and **Key=** before your file name.

Comment: Great to hear. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean [`delete_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object) rather than `delete_file`.

Comment: Iam Getting like this 
**TypeError: delete_object() only accepts keyword arguments.**